# Polyline path in 2D - find all nearest passing of landmark points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d

Given a poly-line path in 2D (like a GPS trace) I am interested in finding all points where the path gets close to existing landmarks. See the diagram below. This could be considered a problem Strava is solving when it reports running time between landmarks.

- The landmarks have a small radius and I am only interested in them when the path crosses through that radius - finding the red dot where the paths is closest to the landmark.
- There are many more landmarks than points on the paths.
- Given a line segment and a landmark it is not difficult to compute the minimum distance using the vector dot product.  The problem is to efficiently find the line segments that pass through landmarks.

[image: paths touching landmarks]

I am not looking for code but the general algorithms and data structures to make this efficient - I lack the background in geometry where this problem is located.

The following properties could be exploited:

- Using the bounding box of the path, the landmarks to be considered could be cut down. Landmarks could be stored in a quad-tree or 2d-tree for this.
- The points of the paths form a sequence. One could walk along the paths only considering the next landmark that could come within reach.
- Landmarks are static, paths change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bird's eye view of multiple proximity data structures including quad- and 2d-trees is that you have a tree where

- Each leaf has a site (here, a landmark point);
- Each interior node has some data that gives a lower bound on the nearest site in its sub-tree.

The lower bound doesn't have to be the minimum; we could just use 0 everywhere (and thereby recover the brute force algorithm). This is the same idea as admissible heuristics in the A* algorithm.

Then to find all sites within some distance r of a query point, we traverse the tree but skip sub-trees where the lower bound is greater than r.

Thing is, this works for query *line segments* too (and many other geometric primitives besides). All we need is code to compute

- The distance from a query primitive to a site,
- A lower bound on the distance from a query primitive to sites in a sub-tree.

You already have the first. With quad- or 2d-trees, for the second, you could use a line-segment-to-box distance, or you could implement something simpler (e.g., maximum separation in either the horizontal or vertical dimension).

Comment: Thank you. The new idea I take from this is that we can use the an approximate distance between a line segment to a landmark by using its bounding box, for example, to find the candidates that are worth exploring in detail.